# Missing Camera and Light

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera, lighting

I am a beginner to blender, and was trying to begin rendering one of my first images. I started to look for the light and camera in order to set up the best possible image. When I tried to do this, my light and camera were missing from the viewport.

After looking around, I found them under the sculpting tab. I was able to move them around in the sculpting tab but have no idea how to return them to the main viewport. I might be completely wrong and they are supposed to be in the sculpting tab, just wasn't sure if it was an issue that I needed to solve to move forward.

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Yeah, here it is: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=W2Y2YPRn" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/W2Y2YPRn/)